# Can't install Ubuntu 20 using Intel RST Raid on Lenovo Thinkstation P330 with NVME SSD Raid

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, ssd, raid, rst

I'm not trying to dual boot Windows or do anything fancy. I'm just trying to combine 2x SSDS to get more storage and maybe a little more performance.

I'm following the official Lenovo Documentation to enable PCI-E Raid on my Thinkstation P330.

It says to go to `Devices -> Configure Sata as Intel RST with Intel Optane -> Create RAID -> Add disks` which is all easy enough.

I'm able to add both NVME SSDs to a RAID 0 array and create it. But when I boot into Ubuntu 20 it says "This computer uses Intel RST. You need to turn off RST before installing Ubuntu".

Is there any way forward to install Ubuntu 20 on an Intel RST RAID array? Lenovos are famously linux compatible but this seems like I'm either doing something wrong or this is a very fringe use case.

Comment: RAID 0 is never recommended for normal use. It was for older HDD to speed systems that always had actual data stored else where. If either drive fails, you lose all data. With Ubuntu MDADM RAID is normally recommended, so you do not depend on hardware. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444499

Comment: Thank you but I don't need warnings about data integrity on RAID 0. All my work is stored on the cloud and reinstalling an operating system is something I do for fun out of boredom. So for now it looks like software RAID at the ubuntu level is the only way forward? I'm not sure how I would create a RAID from a boot device that's in-use and currently running Ubuntu but I can dig a little.